# Play audio from AVAudioPCMBuffer with AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I have two classes, `MicrophoneHandler`, and `AudioPlayer`. I have managed to use `AVCaptureSession` to tap microphone data using the approved answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850392/get-iphone-mic-data-for-streaming-over-socket/33860632?noredirect=1), and and converted the `CMSampleBuffer` to `NSData` using this function:

```
func sendDataToDelegate(buffer: CMSampleBuffer!)
{
    let block = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(buffer)
    var length = 0
    var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = nil

    var status = CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(block!, 0, nil, &length, &data)    // TODO: check for errors

    let result = NSData(bytesNoCopy: data, length: length, freeWhenDone: false)

    self.delegate.handleBuffer(result)
}
```

I would now like to play the audio over the speaker by converting the `NSData` produced above to `AVAudioPCMBuffer` and play it using `AVAudioEngine`. My `AudioPlayer`class is as follows:

```
var engine: AVAudioEngine!
var playerNode: AVAudioPlayerNode!
var mixer: AVAudioMixerNode!

override init()
{
    super.init()

    self.setup()
    self.start()
}

func handleBuffer(data: NSData)
{
    let newBuffer = self.toPCMBuffer(data)
    print(newBuffer)

    self.playerNode.scheduleBuffer(newBuffer, completionHandler: nil)
}

func setup()
{
    self.engine = AVAudioEngine()
    self.playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

    self.engine.attachNode(self.playerNode)
    self.mixer = engine.mainMixerNode

    engine.connect(self.playerNode, to: self.mixer, format: self.mixer.outputFormatForBus(0))
}

func start()
{
    do {
        try self.engine.start()
    }
    catch {
        print("error couldn't start engine")
    }

    self.playerNode.play()
}

func toPCMBuffer(data: NSData) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer
{
    let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.PCMFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 2, interleaved: false)  // given NSData audio format
    let PCMBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: UInt32(data.length) / audioFormat.streamDescription.memory.mBytesPerFrame)

    PCMBuffer.frameLength = PCMBuffer.frameCapacity

    let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: PCMBuffer.floatChannelData, count: Int(PCMBuffer.format.channelCount))

    data.getBytes(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(channels[0]) , length: data.length)

    return PCMBuffer
}
```

The buffer reaches the `handleBuffer:buffer` function when `self.delegate.handleBuffer(result)` is called in the first snippet above.

I am able to `print(newBuffer)`, and see the memory locations of the converted buffers, but nothing comes out of the speakers. I can only imagine something is not consistent between the conversions to and from `NSData`. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Skip the raw `NSData` format

Why not use `AVAudioPlayer` all the way? If you positively need `NSData`, you can always load such data from the `soundURL` below. In this example, the disk buffer is something like:

```
let soundURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("sound.m4a")
```

It makes sense to record directly to a file anyway for optimal memory and resource management. You get `NSData` from your recording this way:

```
let data = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(soundURL.path())
```

The code below is all you need:

**Record**

```
if !audioRecorder.recording {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        audioRecorder.record()
    } catch {}
}
```

**Play**

```
if (!audioRecorder.recording){
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioRecorder.url)
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch {}
}
```

**Setup**

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: self.directoryURL()!,
        settings: recordSettings)
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
} catch {}
```

**Settings**

```
let recordSettings = [AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(44100.0)),
    AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue))]
```

---

**Download Xcode Project:**

You can find this very example [here](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-32342486). Download the full project, which records and plays on both simulator and device, from [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes).

Comment: We need the NSData raw format to transmit it over a socket. We are streaming audio.

Comment: file to `NSData` comes out of the box. Can you think of the file as just a buffer? It happens to be a disk buffer, but it still is just a buffer?

Comment: How do we clear the buffer every time we send a packet of NSData over the socket? @SwiftArchitect

Comment: You need a circular buffer for streaming: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8646156/218152

Comment: @SwiftArchitect Can we Use Above Coe To Transmit Real time data from mic as i need real time nsdata to transfer over socket and play on another device And by saving it into file i think i would not be able to live stream your suggestions ? Thanx

Comment: this question is quite old, I am in the same situation @ConnorHicks have you solved above issue?